# can we use electron in backend like in a server side

Tags: node.js, electron

Is it possible to run nodejs code in **Electron** (use it for server-side), if there's any way to do it.
I'm already using electron in front-end, maybe i will include the code of the server part in same app.

Answer (score 0):

While ultimately you could, there is no need. Simply use node, which is what Electron is running under the hood anyways. Server-side applications have no need for a GUI.